# android facebook integration online friend and send inbox message

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

I integrated the Facebook in my Android application and I use this code to get the friends:

```
try {

  Facebook mFacebook = new Facebook(Constants.FB_APP_ID);
  AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString("fields", "birthday");
  mFacebook.request("me/friends", bundle);

}catch(Exception e){
  Log.e(Constants.LOGTAG, " " + CLASSTAG + " Exception = "+e.getMessage());
}
```

Is there a way to get the online friends?

And I post to walls of friends with this method:

```
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    parameters.putString("message", message);
    parameters.putString("description", "integrating stuff");
    try {
        facebook.request("me");
        String response = facebook.request("me/feed", parameters, "POST");
        Log.d("Tests", "got response: " + response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("") ||
            response.equals("false")) {
            showToast("Blank response.");
        }
        else {
            showToast("Message posted to your facebook wall!");
        }
    finish();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showToast("Failed to post to wall!");
        e.printStackTrace();
        finish();
    }
```

Is there a way to send message to friends' inbox, and not post in the wall?

Answer (score 0):

You get online friends if you are Facebook chat clients which is very different thing.
Till now you cannot send private message there is [send dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/) but I didn't try to use it before